# where to place the public directory for play framework after using the dist command

Tags: java, playframework-2.3

I am using the 'dist' command with play framework v2.5.  However, when I unzip the file, it does not create the public directory.  I have the following directories:
bin, conf, lib, logs and share (contains doc).

Where should I place the public directory whereby this would work exactly like it does with the play framework (not having run the dist command) i.e. I can place static assets in the public directory and have them served from there (I do not wish to use a CDN for this purpose as of now).

I would ideally like the dist command to take care of it (as opposed to manually creating directories).  Will the static route serve images from the public directory or do I need to write my own controller to serve these static assets?

Answer (score 3):

As explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37180103/5715934) answer, add these lines into your /build.sbt file.

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.MappingsHelper._
    mappings in Universal ++= directory(baseDirectory.value / "public")
```

That would include your 'public' directory inside the dist file (You can include any directory like that way). Then your application would work in the production environment.

Comment: activator seems to be unable to load the file without issues - perhaps I need to revisit the build.sbt file - will update later,  thanks

Comment: I stopped using the public directory - and I have stopped using the dist command as well.  I remember I had issues with activator with your suggestion - I will revisit when time permits and accept your answer - thank you so much

Comment: @alihaider is this fine for you? ;)